# Reading CSV in pyspark if there is no header on csv

Tags: pyspark, rdd

How do I create a RDD from CSV file which does not have a header and how do i combine 2 RDD on a column. Not using Spark SQL

```
rdd1 = sc.textFile('transactions.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want a DataFrame or an RDD. If it is the former try:

```
spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "false").load("transactions.csv")
```

The columns will be auto-generated. If it is the latter, do something like:

```
rdd1 = sc.textFile('transactions.csv').map(lambda row: row.split(","))
```